# Android Licensing Server on a device

Tags: android, android-lvl

I'm trying to figure out the whole Android licensing thing, and getting frustrated.
In the emulator, I run the app with no account, or one that isn't in the testing environment, and it seems to work correctly, returning the not licensed response and pops up the buy the app now message.

When I try to run it on an actual Android device, it returns licensed every time, even though the device account isn't one that is in the testing environment.
Also, even though it returns licensed, the "checking license" box never goes away, unless you click cancel. Then it just lets you use the app as if it was licensed.
It's mostly C&P from the example, with a few changes. I removed the check license button and the status text box.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mHandler = new Handler();

    // Try to use more data here. ANDROID_ID is a single point of attack.
    String deviceId = Secure.getString(getContentResolver(), Secure.ANDROID_ID);

    // Library calls this when it's done.
    mLicenseCheckerCallback = new MyLicenseCheckerCallback();
    // Construct the LicenseChecker with a policy.
    mChecker = new LicenseChecker(
        this, new ServerManagedPolicy(this,
            new AESObfuscator(SALT, getPackageName(), deviceId)),
        BASE64_PUBLIC_KEY);
    doCheck();

    ArrayAdapter<String> booksAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mBooks);

    this.setListAdapter(booksAdapter);
}

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    // We have only one dialog.
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setTitle(R.string.unlicensed_dialog_title)
        .setMessage(R.string.unlicensed_dialog_body)
        .setPositiveButton(R.string.buy_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                Intent marketIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(
                    "http://market.android.com/details?id=" + getPackageName()));
                startActivity(marketIntent);
                finish();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton(R.string.quit_button, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                finish();
            }
        })
        .create();
}

private void doCheck() {
    setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(true);
    alertbox("status", getString(R.string.checking_license));
    mChecker.checkAccess(mLicenseCheckerCallback);
}

protected void alertbox(String title, String mymessage)  
{  
    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)  
       .setMessage(mymessage)  
       .setTitle(title)  
       .setCancelable(true)  
       .setNeutralButton(android.R.string.cancel,  
          new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
          public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton){}  
         })  
      .show();  
}

private void displayResult(final String result) {
    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            alertbox("status", result);

            setProgressBarIndeterminateVisibility(false);
        }
    });
}

private class MyLicenseCheckerCallback implements LicenseCheckerCallback {
    public void allow() {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        // Should allow user access.

        //displayResult(getString(R.string.allow));
    }

    public void dontAllow() {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        //displayResult(getString(R.string.dont_allow));

        // Should not allow access. In most cases, the app should assume
        // the user has access unless it encounters this. If it does,
        // the app should inform the user of their unlicensed ways
        // and then either shut down the app or limit the user to a
        // restricted set of features.
        // In this example, we show a dialog that takes the user to Market.
        showDialog(0);
    }

    public void applicationError(ApplicationErrorCode errorCode) {
        if (isFinishing()) {
            // Don't update UI if Activity is finishing.
            return;
        }
        // This is a polite way of saying the developer made a mistake
        // while setting up or calling the license checker library.
        // Please examine the error code and fix the error.
        String result = String.format(getString(R.string.application_error), errorCode);
        displayResult(result);
    }
}

@Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    mChecker.onDestroy();
}
```

I just don't know what I need to change to make it work... or if the license is somehow cached (even though this is the first time I've run it on this device) and if I can uncache it without wiping the device, as that'll be nice for when I do testing on other apps.
Also, how do I remove the "checking license" message without having to click the cancel button... should I just make it so that it doesn't show up?

Comment: Question I have: How to clear the alertbox() dialog box that gets called in doCheck() from within the MyLicenseCheckerCallback.allow() function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm just getting into licensing myself so don't take this as gospel but a few things stick out:

> or if the license is somehow cached (even though this is the first time I've run it on this device) and if I can uncache it without wiping the device, as that'll be nice for when I do testing on other apps.

You are using the [ServerManagedPolicy](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/licensing.html#ServerManagedPolicy) so the approval *will* be cached and obfuscated. This is the recommended way to do it. ( I assume to provide a better user experience and better response time ) In order to debug your approval you need to log into your [market profile](http://market.android.com/publish/editProfile) and change the "Test response" option. You need to use a device that has the same account as your publisher profile for the test response to work for a app that isn't released to the market yet.

You also have no code in your allow() method for your MyLicenseCheckerCallback class which should probably be where you clear the dialog (outside the isFinishing conditional).

> if I can uncache it without wiping the device, as that'll be nice for when I do testing on other apps

Based on LicenseValidator.java It looks like the approval is stored in a prefs file at com.android.vending.licensing.ServerManagedPolicy in private mode. You can use the [sharedpreferences editor](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.Editor.html) to clear it from another place in the app.

Again I'm not a pro on this yet so I could be wrong but I think you might be able to troubleshoot your bug if you get it configured right.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm pretty new to this too, and to java/android programming in general. is there an example of the MyLicenseCheckerCallback in the sample application? I didn't see it, and pretty much C&P everything that I'm using. I'll look at it again, see what I can find.